# How does mnemonic recover a single private key?

Tags: private-key, seed, recover-private-key, mnemonic-seed

As I understand the algorithm of mnemonic (BIP39) can generate billions of private keys from your 14-24 words.

Whats the mechanism that some wallets/clients use to recover a single private key, my private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, they just pick the first one that the mnemonic generates.